# DiskPart script failing on Win10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, diskpart

I recently created a powershell to automatically create an DiskPart script and run it automatically. The script is intented to mount a certain partition on disk 2 to an empty NTFS folder. The following is the script:

```
$sss = "select disk 2`n"
$sss += "select partition 5`n"
$sss += "assign mount=j:\Upload`n"

$log = ".\log\drive_management\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyMMdd_HHmmss')-mount.log"

$script = '__tmp.dps'

Set-Content -Path $script -Value $sss

Start-Process -FilePath "DiskPart.exe" -ArgumentList "/s $($script)" -Verb runas

del $script

echo 'Done!'

pause
```

This worked perfectly if I run the resulting DiskPart script in a powershell prompt, but it failed silently with no log output, no error, no werid prompt and nothing changed if all these are done with the script. I'm new with all these scripts and I've spend some 2 hours debuging and looking for related material. Please help me!

My testing platform is Win10, laptop. Disk 2 is an external 1TB USB HDD. I'm sure there is a partition 5.

Comment: So what happens if you manually run it on your laptop? Which commands work and which don't?

Comment: @Seth ah, I only tested it on my laptop. Question updated.

Comment: Try renaming the script to have a txt extension instead. AFAIK diskpart will only use scripts with that extension.

Comment: @CConard96 oh, no. It can't be that simple... anyway, I'll try it later as that laptop isn't accessible now.